# Actionbar tabs + multiple pane view in android

Tags: android

I want to develop android application like [Design](http://c1345842.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/assets/cdn_files/assets/000/002/355/original.png?1306257738)

> I Googled it.I couldn't find out proper solution to this. Please anyone help me. Without page view, i can able to do mutiple pane option.

Please anybody guide me .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be needing ViewPager for the two tabs. Then you'll use SlidingMenu for the Stories Category. Inside each created Menu, put a listview with a Customized Array Adapter. You  can consider, using fragments also for flexibility of your UI design in small and large screens. I can't provide the codes but these links have all the necessary things you needs specially starting with fragments.

**Download the Sample code here:**

[Effective Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html) -this should help you with your tabs with Pager effect

**SlidingMenu Library:**
[Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

**[Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ready-made template in Eclipse which allows for action bar tabs. Just select the navigation mode as "Fixed tabs+swipe" when you create a new project/activity. After that you can alter/add the fragments based on your requirement using the getItem() method. This is the screen I am talking about http://puu.sh/3h1al.png